# Notepad++ macro in menu bar with icon

Tags: macros, notepad++, customization

I'm looking for a way to add a macro as an icon in the toolbar.

It seems possible to bind keys to the macro, customize the toolbar with [Customize Toolbar](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/11118/customize-toolbar-new-version-4-1) and use [toolbarIcons.xml](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Toolbar_Customisation) to customize it. But none of those options provide an option to add a recorded macro as an icon to the toolbar in Notepad++.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said this can be achieved with CustomizeToolbar plugin. Just follow tyhese steps:

1. Install CustomizeToolbar plugin (you can find it [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-customize/) on Sourceforge)
2. Restart notepad++
3. Enable custom buttons checking Plugin/Customize Toolbar/Custom Buttons:

   [image]
4. Notepad++ will ask you to restart:

   [image]
5. Open `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\plugins\config\CustomizeToolbar.btn` and add this line: `Macro,YourMacroName,,,` replacing `YourMacroName` with the name of your macro
6. Restart notepad++
7. A new button should appear in the toolbar:

   [image]

Comment: thanks, that's what I was looking for, must have missed this part

Comment: Thanks very much for this plugin. Please not that "macro" is name of the menu - it may be language dependent - in German language it is "Makro".